# Can I use .sort() to sort an array of objects based on a number property?

Tags: javascript

If I had an array of numbers, I can quickly sort them using .sort() function like this:

```
let array = [1, 5, 3, 2, 9, 6];
let sortedArray = array.sort();
```

However, I am wondering if I can even use .sort() if my array is made up of objects who have a number property. For example, I'm wondering if I could turn this:

```
let array = [
    { name: "Random1", number: "1" },
    { name: "Random2", number: "5" },
    { name: "Random3", number: "3" },
    { name: "Random4", number: "2" },
    { name: "Random5", number: "9" },
    { name: "Random6", number: "6" },
]
```

Into this based on the value of the number property.

```
let array = [
    { name: "Random1", number: "1" },
    { name: "Random4", number: "2" },
    { name: "Random3", number: "3" },
    { name: "Random2", number: "5" },
    { name: "Random6", number: "6" },
    { name: "Random5", number: "9" },    
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by passing the `compareFunction` as the [parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Parameters) to `sort()`.

`compareFunction | Optional`

> Specifies a function that defines the sort order. If omitted, the array elements are converted to strings, then sorted according to each character's Unicode code point value.

```js
let array = [
    { name: "Random1", number: "1" },
    { name: "Random2", number: "5" },
    { name: "Random3", number: "3" },
    { name: "Random4", number: "2" },
    { name: "Random5", number: "9" },
    { name: "Random6", number: "6" },
]

array.sort((a, b) => (a.number > b.number) ? 1 : -1);
console.log(array);
```

If the *number* property is always *number* in the form of string then use the following:

```
array.sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number);
```

Comment: May I ask what is the difference between your example, and dev_junwen's example? They're similar yet yours has an extra ternary if statement.

Comment: @Bobimaru, the difference is for the type actually---string and number:)

Answer (score 1):

The `sort` method accepts a comparison function. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

`array.sort((first, second) => first.number - second.number);`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the array sort function callback to compare the object property `number`.

```js
const array = [
    { name: "Random1", number: "1" },
    { name: "Random2", number: "5" },
    { name: "Random3", number: "3" },
    { name: "Random4", number: "2" },
    { name: "Random5", number: "9" },
    { name: "Random6", number: "6" },
];

const sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number);
console.log(sortedArray);
```